# USB-C -> USB-C (power) + USB-A (data) splitter cable

Tags: usb, usb-c

I need to make a splitter cable that would allow to charge my iPad (with a USB-C port) from a USB-C charger and at the same time transfer data to another device via USB-A connector. There’s a similar project but with USB-C connectors on all ends. https://www.tindie.com/products/clarahobbs/pd-buddy-wye/

I got it working by connecting data and power lines accordingly, then connecting CC on the charging cable to GND via 5.1kOhm resistor (to advertise a device is connected) and connecting CC on iPad cable to USB-A VСС or USB-C VBUS via 10kOhm resistor (to advertise the charger can output 5V/3A).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvPc3a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Does this solution look correct/good?

ALso, interestingly, the resistors are required for iPad but my GoPro, for example, works if I just connect CC lines directly on both USB-C cables. I don't understand what the difference can be there. Connecting CC lines would be better because as I understand currently the charger will always think there's a device connected.

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: I'm asking if this solution is good enough to use. And optionally, what may be causing iPad and GoPro behave differently without the resistors.

Comment: This is massively against spec. And your go pro probably doesn't support dual host and peripheral roles so it's usb/ power setup is simpler. Apple tends to do their own thing too. I'm surprised it works tbh.

Comment: This is very definitely not allowed, and may damage any or all of the devices connected.

Comment: Can you elaborate pls, what's _massively_ against the spec here? The data part here is exactly a normal USBA/C cable, and the charging part is a normal USB-C charging cable with a broken CC line.

Comment: There are off the shelf solutions for this, is there a reason you are attempting to build rather than buy?  That is unless I'm missing the goals here.

Comment: @MacGuffin Do you have an example? I know there are splitters on Ebay with resistors so essentially are same as this, and there are powered hubs with lots of ports which is more than I need to connect iPad to head unit and power in my car.

Comment: @pronvit  It appears I am confused on what ends you are trying to reach.  Could you edit the question to clarify what is intended to be the USB bus master, which is the bus slave?  What is the power source, and what is the sink?  An iPad will not draw more power than it is told is safe.  For low power, 12 watts and less, it senses resistance **on the data lines**.  For more than 12 watts it uses the USB-PD serial data protocol on the CC lines.  I suspect you can't get to where you want to go with just some resistors.

Comment: USB-C spec specifies pull-up resistor values to advertise port power supplying capabilities. 56kOhm for standard USB power, 22kOhm for 1.5A, and 10kOhm for 3A.

Comment: @pronvit You really need to edit the question to clarify the end goal.  Is the iPad the master of the USB bus or a slave?  How much power are you trying to get?  What are the capabilities of the other devices on the USB bus?  And again, you need to tell the **iPad** it is safe to pull more power so you need to play by it's rules.  For the iPad to draw power from the USB bus it is going to look for a resistor network on the **data** pins or use the serial USB-PD protocol on the CC pins.  Perhaps I'm mistaken but I'm quite sure that resistors on the CC pins are insufficient for your goals.